# Graphing High's and Low's on MatLab

Tags: matlab

How would I go about placing a red circle at the place on a graph with the highest location and a black square where the lowest location is on MatLab? Does it have to be a 2D graph?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what kind of graph you are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will plot y against t, calculate the maximum value and plot a red circle around the maximum value.

```
t = 1:10;
y = rand(1,10);
plot(t,y)
[maxy,imaxy] = max(y);
hold on
plot(t(imaxy),maxy,'ro')
```

Calculating the minimum and placing a black box is left as a exercise for the OP but shouldn't be difficult given sufficient understanding of my example.